# new errors in google maps

Tags: javascript, html, maps

I'm getting different errors in the developer's console with my javascript for google maps and wondering if someone can help me understand them.

ive previously asked a similar question, but now I'm getting new errors.
I'm new to javascript. So here are my two errors below. if anyone would like to see anything more please let me know.

javascript

```
var map = new google.maps.Map({         
div: '.map',
lat: 52.760514,
lng: -1.6500,
zoom: 12
});

});
if (52.7610273, -1.7181805) {

}

 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    lat: 52.7604902,
    lng: -1.7172825,
    title: 'lw swim school',
    infoWindow: {
        content: '<p>LW swim school</p>'
    }
});
```

html

```
 </section>
<!--section 5-->
<span class="anchor" id="touch"></span>
<div class="section">

    <div class="map-box js--section-map">

        <div class="map" id="map-1"></div>

        <div class="form-box" id="form">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>Get in Touch</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <form method="post" action="mailer.php" class="contact-form">

                    <div class="row">

                        <?php
                        if($_GET['success'] == 1) {
                            echo "<div class=\"form-messages success\">Thank you! your message has been sent.</div>";
                        }

                        if($_GET['success'] == -1) {
                            echo "<div class=\"form-messages error\"> Oops! something went wrong. Please try again!</div>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
```

Here are my HTML scripts

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=></script>
<script src="resources/js/gmaps.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/script.js"></script>
```

Here are the two new errors.

```
common.js:114 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 
'defaultView' of undefined
 at new _.kt (common.js:114)
 at Object.mw.h (map.js:75)

Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined at script:41
```

Comment: yeah there is perhaps too much stuff in your example that is not necessary, and perhaps some stuff missing but I think probably you should do new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-1'), options object here ) -- by too much stuff I mean you have php code, lots of scripts referenced. People like it you just put in the code that has to do with the mapping solution and nothing else, so they can put it in their environment  and rewrite it quickly. I realize this might be difficult for you to do. So I hope this comment helps.

Comment: ```<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=></script>``` Did you add your API key, or did you remove it when posting the question?

Comment: User254694, thanks for advice and I will edit the post for only applicable scripts for the map.

Comment: Pieter stein, I did remove my API key before posting.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not the real solution, but did you set up your payment information correctly? 
We had all sorts of errors that were fixed after we set up the payment information in your Google API account.

Comment: Randyk, yes as far as I’m aware my GCP account is in order. As everything was all showing up until I forced my website traffic to go through HTTPS once purchasing an SSL certificate through Go daddy.